# Python pandas timedelta64 fillna

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I have a dataset with hundreds of columns. Some of the columns have timedelta64 type. When i use

```
fillna(0)
```

I got an error `Passing integers to fillna for timedelta64[ns] dtype is no longer supported.  To obtain the old behavior, pass pd.Timedelta(seconds=n)`

How can i fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to update the columns separately accordingly to their dtypes:

```py
# Update inplace numeric columns
df.update(df.select_dtypes('number').fillna(0))

# Update inplace timedelta columns
df.update(df.select_dtypes('timedelta64[ns]').fillna(pd.Timedelta(seconds=0)))
```

Another possible syntax for updating:

```
df.loc[:, df.dtypes.eq(float)] = df.select_dtypes(float).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error use:

```
df['columnname'].fillna(pd.Timedelta(seconds=0))
```

> Passing an integer to Series.fillna() and DataFrame.fillna() with timedelta64[ns] dtypes is deprecated, will raise TypeError in a future version. Use obj.fillna(pd.Timedelta(...))

Comment: Is it correct if dataset has columns with other types (object, int)?

Comment: Sorry but are you asking whether you can use `fillna(0)` for all other `dtype`? You may have to use `fillna("")` for strings. It depends on the `dtype`